# Android Custom ListViewItem Layout

Tags: java, android, xml, intellij-idea

I dont quite get the layout of my List View Item doesnt show like I want it to.
I hope somone would give me some hints since i cannot make it work for quite some time now.
What i want is as follows:

[image]

Here is my approach:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="20dip"
android:padding="6dip">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dip">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/nametext"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="7dip">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/photo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toptext"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/middletext"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
            />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dip"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/bottomtext"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="marquee"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/stars"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="6dip"
            android:src="@drawable/icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
I already tried different sizes and a RelativeLayout. No change.
It doesnt look anythik like i thought it should.

edit three blanks missing

edit2 added pic

Comment: im sorry. the whole xml code is in the text, but it wont show. please anyone that can edit, change this, i dont know how. to see full xml use the edit mode. sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this with LinearLayouts, but you'll need three nested layouts:

1. A vertical LinearLayout containing everything.
2. A horizontal LinearLayout containing everything aside from the heading.
3. A vertical LinearLayout containing the non-heading TextViews.

The inner vertical LinearLayout will probably need `android:layout_weight="1"` so it stretches to fill the available space but doesn't squeeze out the right-hand ImageView.

That's all very expensive, particularly when multiplied by the numerous views in a ListView.  A RelativeLayout can get this done with only one layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dip" >
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
        android:textSize="40sp">
    </TextView>
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" >
    </ImageView>
    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/imageView2" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:src="@drawable/icon" >
    </ImageView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView2" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView3" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/textView4" 
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1" 
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
        android:text="TextView" >
    </TextView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

*Edited for formatting and to add*:

This is the result.  Of course, text and image sizes need adjusted, but the basic result is what you've described.

[image: ListView screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if you really want to have a 3dip headline and 7dip content... 
if you want the stuff inside the outer linearlayout vertical arranged, use

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

in the parent LinearLayout. to arrange the three items in the content part of your layout, you might use android:weight or android:alignParentLeft / Right.

I fear im not sure waht you want to do, so i can not edit your layout :(

Comment: Hi red. first of all thanks for editing. i will add a picture to show what i want. yes i know. all pixel values are random. i fiddled a lot with this. give me a sec to do a little pint.